# angular 4 filter pipe used with server pagination

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-pipe

I am using filter with pagination. It works fine but the problem is that when i search Name it filters the result but pagination remains the same like if search result return 3 filter records the pagination stills shows pages and user can navigate these pages. I want to change my pagination number with search filter. Here is my example code

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="username" [(ngModel)]="_userListParams.UserName" class="form-control">

<pagination-controls (pageChange)="pageChanged($event)" (pageChange)="Paging.currentPage = $event"></pagination-controls>

      <table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th *ngFor="let cell of tableData2.headerRow">{{ cell }}</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr [routerLink]="['/UserDetails', row.Id]" *ngFor="let row of tableData2.dataRows | filter: 'Name':  _userListParams.UserName | paginate: { itemsPerPage: Paging.pageSize, currentPage: Paging.currentPage,totalItems: Paging.totalCount} ;let i = index;">
                                    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row.Name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row.TypeName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row.Country}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row.Status}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row.ItemsQty}}</td>
                                    <td><img class="panel-profile-img" height="70" width="70" src="{{imgurl+row.ProfilePic}}" alt=""></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr *ngIf="tableData2.dataRows.length == 0">
                                    <td colspan="7" class="text-center text-danger">No Record Found!</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Here is my pipe i am using

```
@Pipe({ name: "filter" })
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[],field: string, searchText: string): any[] {
      if(!items) return [];
      if(!searchText) return items;
      searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
       return items.filter( it => {
           debugger;
        return it[field].toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
      });
     }
  }
```

Attached Image

[image]

Comment: you are using multiple pipes, i think the "paginate" pipe is more interesting for your question

Comment: yes i have to use multiple pipes to achieve my goal.

Comment: You should really avoid using a [pipe for filtering](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe), instead just filter in the component using array methods or RxJS.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `autoHide` option on the `<pagination-controls>` element to force it to disappear if all results fit onto page 1.

Documentation linked to the relevant section: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pagination#api

Edited to remove my suggestion to remove the `totalItems` option. Missed the part of the title where you said "server pagination". Facepalm.